# Best way to add images to arrays of objects

Tags: reactjs

I’m creating an array of objects. And I want each object to render a few props including an image.

My question is what is the best way to get the image into each objects state. I can do it fine using the import statement. However as the list gets longer I’m going to end up having a thousand imports for different images.

```
import image from './rusty.jpg';

class DogsList extends Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state= {
          dogs:[
             {name : 'rusty', breed : 'kelpie', image: image},
             {name : 'rex', breed : 'cattle dog', image: image},
             {name : 'rocksea', breed : 'collie', image: image},
          ]
       }
    }
 }
```

At the moment I’m using the import statement as above, but if possible I’d like to store all the pictures in a seperate folder of their own and call them straight into state without the import statement. Is this possible maybe using the require() method ?

I won’t post all the render methods as it has searchboxes and filters all of which are working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to include the actual image as part of the state? Why not keep just the image’s relative path from your public folder as part of the state?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry I’m still quite new to react, at the moment the only way I can get it is by importing the images. However I want to solve the issue of having endless amounts of import statements, because every time I add a new dog to the list I will need to import another picture etc.

Comment: {Name:'rusty',Breed: 'kelpie', image: '/static/images/rusty.jpg'}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps (which I follow to include images in my projects)...

1. Store images in public folder (Let's assume images are inside `public/images` folder)
2. Create a `js` file (Let's assume it is in src folder with name `images`)
3. Inside `images.js` create an object (Let's name it `IMAGES`) where the object contains a list of objects where each object reference to an image

   `src/images.js`

   ```
   export const IMAGES = {
      rusty: { breed : 'kelpie', url: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/rusty.jpg'},
      rex: { breed : 'cattle dog', url: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/rex.jpg'},
      rocksea: { breed : 'collie', url: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/rocksea.jpg'} 
   }
   ```
4. Now `import` this `src/images.js` file where you want to use it. That's it

   In your case, you can rewrite that component as follow

   ```
   import { IMAGES } from 'src/images.js';

   class DogsList extends Component{
      constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state= {
             dogs:[IMAGES.rusty, IMAGES.rex, IMAGES.rocksea]
          }
       }
    }
   ```

I hope this steps will help you, thanks :)

Comment: The problem is I have more then just images in the array of objects. So I want to be able to store the images somewhere and call them in. All I’m trying to do is elimate the need for hundreds of seperate imports. So the above static images idea might be the one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, You will store images inside `src` folder, right? @Cmcco91

Comment: Src or public which ever it doesn’t matter. I’m just trying to find the easiest and neatest way. I anticipate having thousands of list items and each one will have probably two pictures so it will be messy if I use an import for every one.

Comment: It's your choice, but two things I want to tell, 1. Static files (images, js, css etc.) should be inside `public` folder instead of `src` , 2. In my solution, there is only one file where you have to made changes if you got any images to add. @Cmcco91

Comment: Ok I’ll have a go a bit later when I get home from work. And get back to you. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can place the files in a new folder inside the public folder,  for example:  /dogimages/rusty.jpg

Then put that straight into your state.

```
 {name:'rusty', breed:'kelpie',     
   image:'/dogimages/rusty.jpg'}
```

This achieves the goal of eliminating the need for endless imports, and makes the code look a lot neater.